# Is there a plural for logic?

Tags: grammatical-number

If I had to phrase "Load logic", where "loading" has to happen for multiple instances of "logic", how would I do it?

For context, I am a programmer, and writing a method called "loadLogic". That method loads multiple units of logical statements and takes an action on them.

Comment: Typically, logical statements are called *predicates*.

Comment: No, logical statements are called _propositions_. _Predicates_ are the part of a proposition that corresponds to the verb (with subject or object) in a clause, or to the function (with arguments) in math. [See here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for how logic is used in language.

Comment: @John: For Boolean logic, where everything has only two values, *predicates* and *propositions* can be viewed as equivalent. A proposition can easily be turned into a predicate which is true if and only if the proposition is true.

Comment: True in the mathematical sense, which may be sufficient. Not at all true in the application of logic to natural language, where redundancy and ambiguity are design features.

Comment: Why not `loadLogicUnits`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In its entry for *logic* as used in computing and electronics, the Oxford English Dictionary has this citation from 1968:

> He separated the ternary circuits into two sets of binary circuits,
>   one based on a positive logic and the other on a negative one. Then he
>   used translating circuits between the two logics and achieved a true
>   ternary output with the aid of a combining circuit.

If you think your readers will be familiar with this use of the plural, there seems to be no reason not to use it.

Comment: I agree.  _Logics_ is also a standardly used plural in mathematical/philosophical literature, as in the title of Haack’s book _Philosophy of Logics_.

Answer (score 8):

In most usages, [*logic*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/logic_1?q=logic) is an uncountable noun, so *load logic* could mean either one logical statement or many of them.

Comment: In the usual plural mass varietal sense of 'many types of logic' (predicate logic, propositional logic, modal logic, quantified logic, ...), _logics_ is perfectly cromulent, just like _15 inks were used in making this drawing_.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is using the word as a collective noun for 'multiple units of logical statements', not for a system of logic. Used in that sense the word is analogous to *cattle* and doesn't have a plural.

Answer (score 3):

I am a programmer, and in the context of programming, I only ever use "logic". Program logic is code. There may be a few lines, or tens of thousands of lines. Even though the code may be modularized, or located in separate files, it's all still the application logic.

This is just my opinion and my usage, not a definitive answer. But if "logics" is the answer, then it should always be used, because no program is ever just one line of code.

Comment: Fair point, but only in the context of a single application or a single coherent unit. But in some cases you need to consider that a single set of code might be achieving something very different than another set. For example, the logic behind an analytics algorithm and the logic behind a piece that renders a cube on the screen. Consider an operating system: During boot up, it loads N number of applications each with their own 'logic'. How does one, in that scenario, pluralize the word logic?

Comment: I came here just to here that, my friend. Upped.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to gather from the scant information you provided, what you meant by *logic*.

Did you mean ...?

- Scripts
- Sequences
- Declarations
- Event/State/Entity relationships
- etc

You might already know that information science borrows from Mathematics to describe multiples of them

- Sets
- Collections
- Lists
- Trees and their nodes

We could, therefore, say we load sets of logic.  We could load **logic sets**.

Perhaps, *set* is too general and ambiguous terminology.

In a previous employment, the term *recipe* was used. We would load **recipes**.

You might try to be have a little fun, and say you have **buckets of logic**. Then, your could say **bouquets of logic** (which was how Mrs Bucket announced her surname was to be pronounced in *Keeping Up Appearances*).

Your logic loading might actually be loading **sequences**. Or **mesh**, **grid**, **partition**.

For example, one of these ...

- public void loadLogic(Sequence a);
- public void loadLogic(Recipe a);
- public void loadLogic(Bucket a);
- public void loadLogic(Bouquet a);
- public void loadLogic(Node a);
- public void loadLogic(LogicSet a);
- public void loadLogic(LogicTree a);
- public void loadLogic(EventTree a);
- etc

You should research the terminology that I had sprinkled about in this response to your question, and perhaps one or more of them is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In it's Greek: logikós. In Latin, the neuter plural is **logica**.

"Physics, mathematics, economics, linguistics, and hydraulics are all words that are singular in sense and are construed as singular, despite their form. They do not have plurals. Politics and ethics, by contrast, are construed as plural but do not readily admit a singular form. Arithmetic and [logic](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/pluralterm.htm) are singular in sense and form, but **do not readily accept a plural. . . .**

You can push it; there are many systems of logic (including a whole logic of plurals), so there exist logics. (This is actually supported in Plural Logic). But it is not common, so you need to determine for yourself what you want to name your product and why.

I would say, load logics, but if you want to be more correct, you can use, **load logica**.

Comment: Where does the quotation come from?

Comment: @TimLymington - [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/pluralterm.htm).

Comment: As a mathematical logician I know plenty of different logics and have read many books and papers about them, some of them written by people who insist on using the old-fashioned (at least among British mathematicians) plural *formulae* instead of *formulas*. Never once have I heard or read the plural *logica* outside Latin phrases.