# Is "legit" a legitimate word?

Tags: abbreviations, is-it-a-word

Is *legit* an actual word, or is it a slang word that has been shortened from *legitimate*?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "actual word." I would consider it slang and avoid it in business or formal communications, but you may find it in some dictionaries.

Comment: 2Legit2Quit - MC Hammer

Comment: I was hoping for the title ***Is "legit" legit?***.

Comment: it's straight up legit.

Comment: it would be discriminitative if it was not

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable word but rather informal.

Comment: I think it's relevant to add to the discussion that, although "legit" is supposed to be a short form of legitimate, it's taken over in some areas as the new "sick", "cool", "wicked" etc. "Dude, you were hammered last night, it was so legit!".

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, it's a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: What *precisely* would make a word illegitimate?

Comment: Using "legit" improves your street credibility.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Exactly, everising is legititimate.

Comment: Appeared in the NYT crossword as a clue for the answer "KOSHER"...

Comment: Someone please make the title "Is "legit" a legit word?"!

Comment: I've always thought that the only difference was that *legit* was negative and *legitimate* was positive.

Comment: Is "OK" an OK word?

Comment: @JohnLawler [Might this interest you?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289775/how-does-the-to-infinitive-work-with-adjectives-like-wrong-and-wise)

Comment: I'm late to this convo, but natch it's legit. In fact, some might say it's totes adorbs.

Answer (score 64):

A string of letters doesn’t have to be in a dictionary to be a word, but, as it happens, there is an entry for *legit* in the Oxford English Dictionary, where it is given as both an adjective and a noun and defined as being a colloquial abbreviation of *legitimate*. The earliest citation is from 1897.

Whether and how you use it is up to you.

Comment: Seems legit. :)

Comment: A noun? How so?

Comment: @James Here's the first OED example: “Bob is envious of Corbett's success as a ***‘legit’***.” And the second: “1897 - National Police Gaz. (U.S.) 26 May 6/1 - Bob now wants to go into the ***‘legit’***.” The entry also mentions the phrase “on the legit”.

Comment: That sounds like a case where an adjective was nouned.

Comment: Probably, just like _natural, final_ and _monthly_.

Answer (score 28):

> Is *legit* an actual word, or is it a slang word that has been shortened from legitimate?

Any "or" question can be broken down into two questions, so let's do that.

> Is *legit* an *actual word*?

There are two common definitions for "actual"; it can mean "existing" or it can mean "genuine". So let's break that down into two questions:

> Is *legit* an *existing word*?

Well, what is a word? In this case I suppose you mean that a word is the textual representation of a meaningful unit of language.

By that measure I would say that *legit* is a word and that moreover it exists.

> Is *legit* a *genuine word*? That is, does it *actually* have the *qualities* of a textual representation of a meaningful unit of language?

I'm pretty sure it does, yes.

So by either definition it would appear that *legit* is an "actual word".

Now to come to your second question:

> Is *legit* a slang word that has been shortened from *legitimate*?

Yes.

So the answer to both halves of your "or" question is "yes".

Summing up: [Seems legit.](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.mandatory.com/media/2012/10/mom-seems-legit-note-parents.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

In almost any context, people would understand what you meant by "legit", but it's not completely cromulent.

Comment: 'Legit' is one thing; but what in the world does 'cromulent' mean? Oxford Dictionaries have never heard of it!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_the_Iconoclast#Embiggen_and_cromulent

Comment: Can it be used as a noun - e.g. 'cromulence'? And how does the verb form? Is it 'cromulentify' or 'cromulesce'?

Comment: @WS2 - no, it doesn't, and neither. Have a "cromulent" day! :-)

Comment: @WS2: Oxford dictionaries notwithstanding, *cromulent* is a perfectly cromulent word, as used by [Professors of Linguistics](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146846/is-there-a-plural-for-logic#comment302878_146876) on a regular basis. :)

Comment: @WS2 Also see *[How popular is the word “cromulent”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49251)* and *[Is “embiggen” considered a formal or slang word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51786)*.

Comment: As you found, *legit* has more wordiness than *cromulent*.

Answer (score 6):

Like Barrie England is saying, it's a colloquial abbreviation of *legitimate*. What needs to be emphasized for non-native speakers is that "legit" is used *colloquially* which means that you should not use this in formal speech or writing.

The [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=legit&defid=214109) entry also alludes to the fact that its use is becoming more synonymous with the slang term *cool*.

Comment: Really important point here. Do NOT use "legit" in formal prose, as it is the wrong register.

Answer (score -1):

It is undoubtedly a shortened version of the word "legitimate".

So it is as much a legitimate word as you are ready to accept language bastardization.

Comment: Your insinuation that English is not an uncultured mutt of a language is in keeping with even a cursory understanding of the tongue's history.

Comment: @DougM Sorry, it was not my intention to convey such insinuation

Comment: There's an "edit" button if you want to change it.

Comment: Nop need, http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002579.html

Comment: @nicolas At what point did English achieve perfect crystallization? Surely some pure baseline must have been achieved at some point for us to be talking about a subsequent decline. How does any language come to be?

Comment: @Dave me do not know. CU.

Comment: @DaveMagner, this is very enlightening. https://www.amazon.com/Unfolding-Language-Evolutionary-Mankinds-Invention/dp/0805080120

Comment: languages in general are not english in particular